# Unable to translate error message in AD B2C custom policy "Unable to validate the information provided."

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are using AD B2C custom policies for our sign-in flows and we are also doing language customization.

Even if it's possible to localize the error messages using custom policies (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids), for example:

```
<LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountsignup.en">
  <LocalizedStrings>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="DefaultUserMessageIfRequestFailed">Failed to establish connection to restful service end point.</LocalizedString>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfCircuitOpen">Unable to connect to the restful service end point.</LocalizedString>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfDnsResolutionFailed">Failed to resolve the hostname of the restful service endpoint.</LocalizedString>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfRequestTimeout">Failed to establish connection to restful service end point within timeout limit.</LocalizedString>
  </LocalizedStrings>
</LocalizedResources>
```

I cannot find a key for the message **"Unable to validate the information provided."**

[image]

Also, it doesn't have an ID.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot customise this error as this occurs when the actual policy has been configured in such a way that it cannot actually handle the users page submission. It indicates your policy has a bug in its logic.

You should troubleshoot why this error is occurring:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot?pivots=b2c-user-flow

One of the validation technical profiles during the sign in technical profile is problematic.

This error will never be displayed to a user with a policy that’s configured to handle all scenarios the can force. Hence there is no localisation available or needed for this error.

Comment: The policy is configured correctly. In fact, if I insert a valid user I can login. The error occurs when I try to login using a username that isn't a valid email. However, I cannot leave it in English and I need to localize it.

Comment: What would be an example of such a bug?

I am getting this error while following the seamless user migration guide, wherein the sign in technical profile contains two validation technical profiles, first validation technical profiles reads the user based on the sign in email address and returns a flag extension_requiresMigration, then based on this flag a second validation technical profile is invoked which sets this flag to false (there is a HTPP TP profile in between the two, I have ommitted it in order to isolate the user update)

Comment: Best to open a new post, and share the validation technical profiles definition.